# mosquitto and mosquitto-auth-plugin giving error mosquitto_auth_acl_check client id not available

Tags: acl, mosquitto

I am using `mosquitto` ver 1.6.9 and `Mosquitto Auth Plugin` to make my mosquitto secure ,

I had been doing the same with a previous machine which was ubuntu 16 and it was all ok , I upgraded that machine to Ubuntu 16 and had  to rebuild the auth plugin as libmysqlclient.so had been changed fro 18 to 20.

Now when I run mosquito with the auth plugin my client devices and apps can connect but the ACLs are not authenticated and I get the following logs

```
1585414235: |-- mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check(username_9786)
1585414235: |-- ** checking backend mysql
1585414235: |-- getuser(username_9786) AUTHENTICATED=1 by mysql
1585414235: |-- mosquitto_auth_acl_check(..., client id not available, username_9786, /iremote/username_9786, MOSQ_ACL_WRITE)
1585414235: |-- aclcheck(username_9786, /iremote/username_9786, 4) AUTHORIZED=0 by none
1585414235: |--  Cached  [0F9BF3164FBDC47DC745F5C7EFB055979FB61134] for (client id not available,username_9786,4)
1585414235: |-- mosquitto_auth_acl_check(..., client id not available, username_9786, /iremote/username_9786, MOSQ_ACL_WRITE)
1585414235: |-- aclcheck(username_9786, /iremote/username_9786, 4) CACHEDAUTH: 17
1585414235: |-- mosquitto_auth_acl_check(..., client id not available, username_9786, /iremote/username_9786, MOSQ_ACL_WRITE)
1585414235: |-- aclcheck(username_9786, /iremote/username_9786, 4) CACHEDAUTH: 17
1585414236: |-- mosquitto_auth_acl_check(..., client id not available, username_9786, dev/udevls, MOSQ_ACL_WRITE)
```

I guess the **client id not available** is the issue , but I am clueless at this point .

Comment: i had to revert to mosquitto 1.4.7 and build it gain with older version of libssl at the moment to solve the issue

Comment: The reason for the above issue is described well here in this SO Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54120778/1155507